# overflow hidden image not show at all when printing

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I have some html to print in Chrome. I want to print it at A4 size like real paper. When I opened the html in chrome, the second image showed part of itself, but did not show at all when printing to PDF. How can I make the printing the same as html screen view.

Some example code: the image I use in the html is on the internet. All the code is in a single html file just copy the html then you can preview it too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @page {
            size: A4;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0
        }

        .A4_page {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            page-break-after: always;
            width: 210mm;
            height: 296mm;
            box-shadow: 0 .5mm 2mm rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        }

        /** For screen preview **/
        @media screen {
            body {
                background: #e0e0e0
            }

            .A4_page {
                background: white;
                box-shadow: 0 .5mm 2mm rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                margin: 5mm auto;
            }
        }

        @media print {
            .A4_page {
                width: 210mm
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="A4_page">
        <img style="margin-left: 40px" width="90%"
            src="https://papers.co/wallpaper/papers.co-nf48-sky-star-circle-space-night-sunset-blue-mountain-6-wallpaper.jpg?download=true"
            alt="">
        <img style="margin-left: 40px" width="60%"
            src="https://papers.co/wallpaper/papers.co-nf48-sky-star-circle-space-night-sunset-blue-mountain-6-wallpaper.jpg?download=true"
            alt="">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

screen view:
[image]
print view:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work? let me know

```css
@media print {
            .A4_page {
                width: 210mm;          
                display:inline-block;

            }
        }
```

Comment: The image dose show. But it push the second images to the next page.

Comment: i edit the code above, try to add it and then let me know.

Comment: It still pushed the second images to the next page.

Comment: add margin:0mm; on the code. see if that will stop it.. put a height:auto as well then let me know

Comment: it doesn't stop it.

Comment: remove code if it doesnt work then add this.object-fit:contain;. if this doesnt work. I want to see how it splits. page-break-before: avoid; try that as well

Comment: It still pushed the second images to the next page. And with `height:auto` I can not get the print view. Looks like it can not be print with `height:auto`.

Comment: @media print {
            .A4_page {
                width: 210mm;
                overflow: visible;
                page-break-after: avoid;
                margin: 0mm;
                object-fit:contain;
            }
        }
The image I will put in post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243944/discussion-between-crystal-and-xinyu).